# itext 7 concat pdf and send to response

Tags: java, itext7

I'm having an array of blobs containing PDFs. I'm trying to append all these PDFs and send the result to the client using the servlet `response.getOutputStream`. But somehow I'm getting a document that is 15 bytes and not readable by Acrobat Reader.

Where data is a `List<Data>` containing some blobs with the Word documents.
I first convert to PDF using Aspose. I'm confident that this code works.
So that can't be the problem.
`Document` object here is an Aspose lib. object that is written to an output stream as PDF.
Problem is that I can't find any documentation on this in the iText 7 doc, nor in the examples.

Here's the code I'm using

```
List<PdfDocument> listPDF = new LinkedList<>();
for (Data aData : data) {
    byte[] input = aData.getBlobValue();  
    ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
    Document srcDocWord = new Document(inStream); 
    ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();         
    srcDocWord.save(pdfOStream, SaveFormat.PDF);
    ByteArrayInputStream pdfIStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfOStream.toByteArray());
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfIStream);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader);
    listPDF.add(pdfDoc);
}       
PdfDocument result = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));
for (PdfDocument pdfDoc : listPDF) {
    pdfDoc.initializeOutlines();
    List<PdfPage> list = pdfDoc.copyPagesTo(1, pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(), result);          
    pdfDoc.close();
}       
System.out.println(result.getNumberOfPages());
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( ((ByteArrayOutputStream)pdfDoc.getWriter().getOutputStream()).toByteArray());
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
os.write(is.read());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Now If I'm having 2 PDFs of 1 document, the sysout returns 2, so that is correct.
But the document returned to the response is only 15 bytes large.

Comment: Hi,  look at the iText 7 api, you'll find it has changed since iText 5. The PdfDocument object is introduced, and according to the doc, the pdfDoc.copyPagesTo is the way to do this. This method returns the 'result object to the servlet, and then I try to stream it.
If found a solution by returning the listPDF object to the servlet, and creating the 'result' object there, using the for loop you see above, and by using the outputstream of the response object, like this :
PdfDocument result = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(response.getOutputStream()));
But it seems a strange way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should close the resultant document.
Second of all, I don't see how you write anything to the response. You only call `os.write(is.read());` which doesn't copy `is` to `os` at all.

Try writing to the `os` right away, this is a much cleaner approach:

```
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
PdfDocument result = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(os));
for (PdfDocument pdfDoc : listPDF) {
    pdfDoc.initializeOutlines();
    List<PdfPage> list = pdfDoc.copyPagesTo(1, pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(), result);          
    pdfDoc.close();
}
result.close();
```